# Synchronizing OpenAPI and JSON-B config using Quarkus

Tags: openapi, quarkus

## The jouney so far

I'm trying to get a REST service up and running, following the [official guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json), using RESTEasy and JSON-B.
I also added support for OpenAPI for testing the service following [this guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui).

Both parts work on their own, the service properly returns the hard coded demo data. The Swagger UI shows the available routes and allows to invoke them.

However, it's not as smooth as I liked it to be...

Playing around, I created a route returning an object containing an `Instant`. Making the call, I'm represented with an ISO 8601 formatted string for the property, just as I would have expected.

The associated schema for the property however is

```
Instant:
  type: object
  properties:
    nanos:
      format: int32
      type: integer
    seconds:
      format: int64
      type: integer
    epochSecond:
      format: int64
      type: integer
    nano:
      format: int32
      type: integer
```

which is not in line with what is actually returned. I sort of get where it's coming from. Apparently, `quarkus-smallrye-openapi` is using a different setup when inspecting the `Instant` from what `quarkus-resteasy-jsonb` is using.

For the latter, I already figured out that a custom `JsonbAdapter` can be used to manipulate the formatting. For example:

```java
public class JsonbInstantTypeAdapter implements JsonbAdapter<Instant, OffsetDateTime> {
    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime adaptToJson(Instant obj) {
        return OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(obj, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }

    @Override
    public Instant adaptFromJson(OffsetDateTime obj) {
        return obj.toInstant();
    }
}

public class TestTimestamps {
    @JsonbTypeAdapter(JsonbInstantTypeAdapter.class)
    public Instant getDueTime() {
        return Instant.now();
    }
}
```

This results in the `Instant` being serialized after being converted into the systems's timezone, which can be easier to read while debugging.

I could only partially figured out how to tweak the schema. Annotating the method like this:

```java
public class TestTimestamps {
    @Schema(type = SchemaType.STRING, format = "date-time")
    public Instant getDueTime() {
        return Instant.now();
    }
}
```

results in a proper example value being generated, but the generated schema still knows it's an instant, so it's generated as

```yaml
dueTime:
    allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Instant'
        - format: date-time
          type: string
```

Ideally, I wouldn't want to annotate every method separately anyways.

## The question

Is there a way to *configure project-wide* to use a certain adapter for a given type?
And is there a way to make sure the generated OpenAPI schema is actually representing that adapted type instead of the original one?

Comment: I have opened this issue to track the problem and fix a fix https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8810

Comment: Thanks for forwarding it. Getting it consistent out of the box would obviously a best case scenario. In the meantime, do you know of a way to configure quarkus-smallrye-openapi independently?

Answer (score 1):

The MicroProfile specification let's you override the schema for a specific class

Adding this in your Quarkus `application.properties` will override the Date schema

```
mp.openapi.schema.java.util.Date = { \
  "name": "EpochMillis" \
  "type": "number", \
  "format": "int64", \
  "description": "Milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT" \
}
```

That would work for your problem with `Instant`.
See https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/microprofile-openapi-spec.adoc#core-configurations

Comment: Unfortunately, this only exists on master of the spec. It's not in microprofile-open-api-1.1.2 (resolved version at the time of writing).

Comment: As far as I can tell this has been included in the spec since 2.0, so for newer implementations this is probably the way to go. It certainly helped me with defining Jsonb's JsonValue as an "object".

Answer (score 0):

A short-term work-around for `Instant` that should work before this is fixed would be to use the `implementation` property of the `@Schema` annotation. The annotation scanner in smallrye-open-api will ignore the type of a bean's method/field when the `implementation` is given (which will get rid of the `$ref` in your example output). This approach would also work for any other Java type that is not represented properly in OpenAPI using its "natural" type.

```java
public class TestTimestamps {
    @Schema(implementation = String.class, format = "date-time")
    public Instant getDueTime() {
        return Instant.now();
    }
}
```